# Padding / default in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this resault from a Hash which works brilliantly in my Javascript. Except for one thing, which only happens on some. Here is the result:

```
[[500,400,300], [650,300], [500,400,300]]
```

You can see in the second member the array is only 2 members long. How can I pad that out so any missing members are 0. So that would be come.

```
[[500,400,300], [650,300,0], [500,400,300]]
```

I've tried using the default method but it doesn't work.

Im geting this Hash by using this code:

```
data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

In a nut shell, I would like all the arrays even and a 0 placed to even them up. Been researching this for ages. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are the chances that one of the elements could contain a single member? `[[500,400,300],[650],[500,400,300]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
def addpadding(data, length)
  data.each do |subarray|
    subarray.fill(0, subarray.length...length)
  end
end
```

You need to provide the 2 dimensional array and the required `length` (eg 3) to the method and it will pad the sub-arrays to the given length.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
a = [[500,400,300], [650,300], [500,400,300]].each {|e| e << 0 if e.count < 3}
#=> [[500, 400, 300], [650, 300, 0], [500, 400, 300]]
```

Comment: what if one of the arrays has only one member. your code will only work when there is one member missing

Comment: @luriG : look at my comment underneath the question, I have asked the same thing.

Comment: all you need is while loop there instead of `if` to make it work for all possibilities, so why not just make it work for all situations?